# User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false after publishing on Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service, session-variables, asp.net-membership

We have a web application developed in MVC which uses Membership providers for authentication.

In one scenario we have a code which checks for **User.Identity.IsAuthenticated** and **HttpContext.Current.Session** but both are returning as false when deployed on Azure. Ref code is -

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Session["LoggedInUserEmail"])))
                    {

                    }
```

This block executes when we run on local, but doesn't work after publishing on Azure.

Can you please guide how can we achieve this?

Comment: `but doesn't work after publishing on Azure.` Is there any exception or error information? Do you have a try to [remote debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio#remotedebug) it ?

Comment: No Exception logged in, not tried with remote debug

Comment: Are you authenticating with Azure AD?

Comment: @Oxygen Did you ever resolve this?